# Have a shell script loop once it reaches the end

Tags: shell, loops

Okay here's what i'm trying to do. I want this script to run every 15 minutes. I have tried using Crontab to run it, but Crontab does not want to work for me. Which is fine there's multiple ways to make this work i'm sure.

I have this script autorun at launch, it executes fine. What i'm looking to do, is have it wait 15 minutes and then re-run from the very beginning. An infinite loop.

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE='wfica'

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
echo "$SERVICE service running, everything is fine"
else
echo "$SERVICE is not running"
/home/rpitc/Desktop/Scripts/Iceweasel.sh & /home/rpitc/Desktop/Scripts/Login.sh
sleep 900
# start over
fi
```

Script executes but doesn't loop. I'm sure this is a simple fix, please excuse my ignorance.

Thanks!

Comment: I would get this working via cron rather than hacking around it. That being said `exec "$BASH_SOURCE"` will re-execute the current script. But this also seems like a script to watch a service in which case neither this nor cron are correct and the correct solution is to use an init or daemon watching tool (of which there are many).

Comment: Thanks Etan, I'll take a look at daemon watching tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE='wfica'

while true; do 
  if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
  then
  echo "$SERVICE service running, everything is fine"
  else
  echo "$SERVICE is not running"
  /home/rpitc/Desktop/Scripts/Iceweasel.sh & /home/rpitc/Desktop/Scripts/Login.sh
  fi
  sleep 900
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
while true; do
Your code here
done;
```

However for such things id add to your service script a call to a python script which could execute the loop take care of the check and also log abnormalities